# Error: Vector iterator not dereferencing

Tags: c++, vector

I just inserted into a vector and all is well, when I went to insert next, with the vector iterator currently pointing at vectorname.begin(). Since I only have one value, the guard I have should stop it from iterating, but it breaks for some reason. I feel like I'm not accessing the end correct, or stopping the iteration.. either way, here's the code that's breaking.

```
// check if iterator X and Y are equal to destX and destY
if(iter != this->playerVector.end())
{
    while((iter->myX != destX) && (iter->myY != destY) || (iter != this->playerVector.end()))
    {
        iter++;
    }
}
```

it breaks when checking the while statements after one iteration.

Comment: Added the C++ language tag; if this isn't right, please change it.

Comment: Show us the insertion code as well, please, and whatever surrounds it.

Comment: Can you post more of your code. You say you did some insertions; where was that? You may have some invalid iterators.

Comment: How does it break? What does `this->playerVector`, `destX` and `destY` contain? Can you please post a full self-contained code sample that I can paste into a file, compile, run and see the error?

Comment: Not really sure what're you trying to accomplish with the while loop's condition `(iter->myX != destX) && (iter->myY != destY) || (iter != this->playerVector.end())`. Can you describe in words?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you are **missing proper conditioning** in the `while` loop and that's why it's **always `true`** (also put braces when you have various operators in place). Your condition should be,

> `while`((iter->myX != destX) && (iter->myY != destY) ***`&&`*** (iter !=
>   this->playerVector.end()))

Following is another simple version of your `while` loop:

```
while(iter != this->playerVector.end())
{
  if(iter->myX == destX || iter->myY == destY)
    break;
  iter++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to do is "// check if iterator X and Y are equal to destX and destY" then you've made it more complex than needed..

```
while(iter != this->playerVector.end())
{
  if(iter->myX == destX && iter->myY == destY) {
    cout << "found destX/Y at " << iter << endl;
    break;
  }
  iter++;
}
```

-- edit --

also know that when you write such looong statements like `x || y ^ z && a & b...`, then you also have to take [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations#Programming_languages) in account, though in this case I guess only problem they cause is to make it unreadable.

Comment: I guess `iter->myX == destX && iter->myY == destY` should be having `||`. From the code it seems that OP wants break the loop when either of `myX` or `myY` are found.

Comment: :).. I saw and was thinking to give you the opposite comment.. IMO "X and Y are equal to destX and destY" translates to `iter->myX == destX && iter->myY == destY` and it also seemed logical.. lets wait for OP's comment..

Comment: Actually `(iter->myX != destX && iter->myY != destY)` is equivalent to `!(iter->myX == destX || iter->myY == destY)`. So I was commenting just by that logic. I am not sure, if OP wants to find either or both. My perception is only from the code given. :)

Comment: I did have to change the || to && and that seemed to work just fine X.X those kind of errors seem to slip past me sometimes. Thanks for the help.